# Poor performance with 4K resolution with GTX 750 Ti

Tags: unity, nvidia, 16.04, xorg, 4k-monitor

I have started using 4K resolution on Ubuntu 16.04 however find that the performance of Unity is poor. Switching between windows or dragging them can be slow, if I set the resolution lower this is no longer an issue.
I am using Nvidia driver 367.44, NVIDIA driver shows low resource usage on  the GPU so am confused where the issue is?

Comment: Hello, did you solve the issue since? I've got a plain GTX 750 with a 4k external monitor, and using the binary nvidia driver everything works just fine. Are you sure you're not using nouveau by mistake?

Comment: Hi Alan, When dragging windows and loading programs its still slightly slower at 4k resolution compared to HD. My nvidia driver is now version 367.57. (proprietary). I am sure I am not short on resources as I have checked these in Nvidia X server settings & system monitor.

Comment: I have turned off "Sync to VBlank" in OpenGL Settings on NVIDIA X Server Settings. This has improved the speed a lot.